# Solving the Schrödinger equation for a rotating triatomic linear molecule

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, rotational-kinematics, rotation, molecular-dynamics

[This source](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/molecule/nno.html#c1) is showing that solving the Schrödinger equation for a triatmoic linear molecule yields the same formula for the rotationaI quantum states $BJ(J+1)$ as for dipoles.

For dipoles, the total rotational energy can be expressed as the total length of the molecule $R$ and a particle with reduced mass $\mu$ which makes it possible to express the coordinates in the Schrodinger equation specifically for only one particle with that reduced mass $\mu$. The sources I used for solving the equation and deriving the energylevel formula is found [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.02%3A_The_Hamiltonian_Operator_for_Rotational_Motion) and [here](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.03%3A_Solving_the_Rigid_Rotor_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation)

I am clueless how the Schrödinger equation is solved for triatomic linear molecules because there are more variables that can not be reduced the same way as mentioned in these two sources. I would therefore expect to be seperate coordinates for each atom in the Schrodinger equation, as well as more than one bond length.

How is it derived and is it actually possible to do so?

Comment: You could try chemistry.stackexchange.

Comment: @handler'shandle Will do, thanks

Comment: @handler's handle why would chemistry.stackexchange help with this question? This is about solving the Schrodingers equation.

Comment: For that matter, solving the Schrodinger equation for any linear rigid rotor, whether it has 2 or 2000 atoms (if such a thing existed), would have the same form. It's just a model.

Answer (score 1):

What is important here is that the molecule is a) rigid (no vibrational degrees of freedom), and b) linear. Thus, the only two things that can happen to the molecule is 1) being displaces as a whole, and 2) rotating about its center-of-mass.

The position of the center-of-mass can be determined as
$$\mathbf{R} = \frac{\sum_i m_i\mathbf{r}_i}{\sum_i m_i},$$
where the sum is over all the particles in the molecule.
Its dipole moment (in respect to the center-of-mass) is
$$\mathbf{D} = \sum_i q_i(\mathbf{r}_i-R),$$
Finally one can calculate in the same way its momen of inertia in respect to the axis passing through the center of mass and perpendicular to the molecule:
$$I = \sum_i m_i\left[\mathbf{n}\times(\mathbf{r}_i-R)\right]^2.$$
We then obtain its energy as
$$E = \frac{\mathbf{P}^2}{2\mu} + \frac{\mathbf{L}^2}{2I}.$$

Note that this derivation is A) completely classical, and B) applicable to a *rigid* and *linear* molecule with any number of atoms (for a non-rigid molecule one has to account for vibrations, whereas for non-linear molecules the rotational part of the Hamiltonian is more complex). Transition to the quantum case means replacing $\mathbf{P}$ and $\mathbf{L}$ by their operators and possibly adding the spin term.

Comment: Sorry but could you please elaborate more what $R$ and $r_i$ are? I know these are distances but with repsect to what? Also, what is **n** in the moment of inertia formula?

Comment: $\mathbf{R}$ is the position of the center-of-mass, whereas $\mathbf{r}_i$ is position of i-th particle. This is basic mechanics - from the level of your question I assumed that you know such things...

Comment: My question is more about with respect to what? But judging from the formula I'd say with respect to 1 of the 2 ends of the molecule. My question in the OP is also about how the coordinates for each atom are expressed for solving the equation.

Comment: In respect to the coordinate origin. Btw, these are 3d vectors.

Comment: @Phy The point is that for a rigid body you need only six variables to charactrize its position: three coordinates if the center of mass and three angles for orientation in space. All other variables are not independent, since it is rigid.

Comment: What I meant is, for diatomics the rotational energy formula can be rewritten such that the 2 atoms can be reduced to 1 particle with a reduced mass and thus just one set of coordinates is needed at a distance $R$ from the origin. How are the three atoms in a triatomic molecule reduced to one particle in order to have one set of coordinates at a distance $R$?

Comment: It works in exactly the same way: the motion is decomposed into displacement of the center-of-mass of the molecule, and the rotation about this center-of-mass. I am not sure what you call the *reduced mass* - here we need only the total mass, $M=\sum_i m_i$ and the moment of inertia, $I$.

Comment: So for the rotation a mass $M$ is considered rotating at a distance $R$ from the origin?

Comment: I see now what *reduced mass* you are talking about. No, it is not $M$... but you don't really need it - what you need is the moment of inertia.

Comment: So there is no certain mass rotating at a certain distance from the origin in this case? Unlike diatomics?

Comment: There are several masses rotating about the *center-of-inertia* (also called *center-of-mass*, while *origin* is usually the *coordinate origin*, which can be anywhere). In case of a diatomic moclecule we have two masses, in case of a three-atomic molecule - three masses.

Comment: That's not what I meant. For diatomics the whole scenario can be reduced to one particle and one bond length rotating around an origin. I assume this can not be done for a triatomic molecule?

Comment: You can, but you do it in the same way: define the center-of-mass, the moment of inertia, and then think of this moment of inertia as a reduced mass rotating about the center-of-mass. But it seems very far from your question, which was about solving the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Why doesn’t the moment of inertia become an operator? Is it because we have a rigid body so there is no uncertainty in the position of the atoms?

Comment: @Tabin yes, this is it. It is an approximation, of course - in principle one should also take into account the vibrational degrees of freedom, i.e. the extension/contraction of the bonds.

Comment: @Vadim  One of my struggles  for solving the Schrödinger equation was how the parameters are defined. So for diatomics the coordinates define the position of the reduced mass while for triatomics the coordinates define the position of the moment of inertia?

Comment: @Phy regardless of the terms, they are solved in exactly the same way. I suggest that you outline in your question how you solve for diatomics, and I will then be able to answer in an understandable way. This discuss is too much about definitions.

Comment: @Vadim [This] (https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.02%3A_The_Hamiltonian_Operator_for_Rotational_Motion) and [this](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Book%3A_Quantum_States_of_Atoms_and_Molecules_(Zielinksi_et_al)/07%3A_Rotational_States/7.03%3A_Solving_the_Rigid_Rotor_Schr%C3%B6dinger_Equation) is what I used for solving for diatomics. They used the wavefunctions as functions of coordinates.